# Get URL Detail for which curl gave Error

Tags: curl

I am searching for a curl command which can used to print the url details too for which the Error actually occurred.

I need this since, i will be firing multiple parallel curl commands. So its hard to track which curl has actually thrown the error.

What i could come up with till now is this which will just print the error logs :

```
curl "http://${HOST}/${CACHE_URL}" --fail --silent --show-error
```

And the sample output that i am getting is :

```
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 3000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 3000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

What i need is the "${HOST}/${CACHE_URL}" details along with this failures.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: `curl -sD - -o /dev/null` will do. Or `-I` option if you don't mind curl to do an HTTP HEAD.

Comment: @jfly thanx for the response .. i tried ur suggestion .. but didnt got what i was looking for.. what i tried is this : curl --max-time ${CURL_TIMEOUT} --retry ${CURL_RETRY} --retry-delay ${CURL_RETRY_DELAY} -sDx ${PROXY_CONFIG} -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate" -o "${OUTFILE}" "http://${HOST}/${CACHE_URL}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although its an Old Query, still answering it incase someone faced this issue and will endup to this link.

So far was not able to find any direct way to get the only url which failed.
Instead what we can do is print all the urls along with its http response code in a file and later you can grep for any particular response code you will be interested in:

```
curl -w "%{http_code} %{url_effective}\n" "http://${HOST}/${CACHE_URL}" >> "curl.log"
```